# How to catch all special characters during string matching?

Tags: python, string, unicode

Is there any way to be able to catch all exceptions when doing string matching? For example if I have a string,

```
print("red" =="red" )
# evaluates to True
```

However,

```
print("Rεժ" == "red")
# evaluates to False
```

What I would like is to be able to catch all the special cases such as the following

```
print("Rεժ" == "red")
print("RêÐ" == "red")
```

to be evaluated to be `True`. The use-case for this is to be able to have some sort of text filtering to be able to catch all the words "red".

Comment: The `confusables` package does exactly this, but both your `d`'s are not recognized by it :(

Answer (score 0):

As Tomalak and Laurens Koppenol eluded to in the comments, this could be a possible duplicate of other SO questions involving UTF8 or Unicode characters with accent marks, but the following code returned true for me:

```
import unidecode

accented_string = u'RêÐ'
unaccented_string = unidecode.unidecode(accented_string)
print(unaccented_string.lower() == "red")
```